# You are debugging a release version of xyz.dll in MS Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, .net-assembly

[image]

I am using existing projects as assembly references and checked all build settings if they are in release mode but all of them are configured as debug (active) builds.

So how to mark the separate projects within a project map as debug mode?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue in VS 2015 context with a DLL-code that I had decompiled using ILSpy.
I ended up updating following line in the AssemblyInfo.cs of the decompiled-DLL-project.

```
[assembly: Debuggable(DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.Default | DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.DisableOptimizations | DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.IgnoreSymbolStoreSequencePoints | DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.EnableEditAndContinue)]
```

Hope something like this works for you too. Good luck.